# Excel nested MATCH?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a spreadsheet (MASTER TIMETABLE) listing a number of venues, days and activities on each day, as shown below:

[image]

In a separate sheet, I want to provide inputs of the Venue and Day, and get an output of the Activity. For example, if I input `VIC - Kennington` (B20) and `Thursday 5th April` (J20), I'd get `The Zone` (J21) as my output.

My problem is that the days change from venue to venue, so I can't just highlight the entire array and use the top row to lookup the Day. I've been able to find out the row to search by using the following formula:

```
=MATCH($B$2,'MASTER TIMETABLE'!B:B,0)
```

Using this, if B2 is `VIC - Kennington`, I'll get an output of `20`. That gives me the row I then need to search for the Day, but I can't seem to figure out how to then pull that into the next MATCH function, e.g.:

```
=MATCH($A$5,'MASTER TIMETABLE'!20:20,0)
```

If I can figure out how to generate the `20:20` part of the formula dynamically, I know that the next step is just a simple offset down by one row, but I can't figure out how to get the formulas to nest. I've also considered using VLOOKUP, but again I can't figure it out.

Comment: You've almost got it. You can use [INDEX(array,row_num,col_num)](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-index-function) to do a 2D lookup. Use MATCH() for the row and col nums as you have shown, and add 1 to the first MATCH(). Good luck. Message back if you need more help.

Comment: You are messing with the Data,, in fact  you are looking for the event on the Date particular, and this can be searched simply by Index and Match. Suppose you want to find event on Thursday 5th,,, so write =INDEX(A20:M27,MATCH(J20,A20:M20,0)) and you get The Zone.

Comment: Why you need 2 Criteria in Row,, which is technically not possible? Since You are trying 2 Column Headings as Criteria !!

Comment: PS. Ignore Rajesh's comments. He misunderstood your question (as usual).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get it to work, using INDEX. Considering the Day columns don't move in relation to the Venue, I can just set the column_num as a static. Nesting that inside an OFFSET gives me the Activity. Here's my final formula:

```
=OFFSET(INDEX('MASTER TIMETABLE'!$B$2:$Z$667,MATCH($B$2,'MASTER TIMETABLE'!$B$2:$B$666,0),5),1,0)
```

Thanks to Bandersnatch for putting me on the right track.

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to help.